Dotnet aspire - workload udpate requires elevated permissions - Sudo can't find command dotnet - M3 Pro MacOS Sonoma
I'm attempting to follow the getting started guide below for .net aspire with VSCode
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/fundamentals/setup-tooling?tabs=linux&pivots=vscode#install-net-aspire
I've installed the Arm dotnet installer and can see

dotnet --version
8.0.300

which i attempt to run

dotnet workload update
Inadequate permissions. Run the command with elevated privileges.

If i attempt to run

sudo dotnet workload update (or even)
sudo dotnet --version

I get dotnet: command not found
I can see the $PATH variable contains the link - /usr/local/share/dotnet ~/.dotnet/tools

So to resolve I deleted the symlinked file in /usr/local/bin and then recreated the symlink
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
and i can now follow the tutorial.
